# Configure ufw to redirect http traffic to another IP

Tags: ubuntu, redirect, ufw

I'm trying to redirect all HTTP/HTTPS trafic from one server to another (via IP).

I do use the `ufw` firewall. How can I configure it do to so?

Answer (score 11):

<sub>(You will need admin privileges for this, so login as root or use sudo accordingly)</sub>

One easy solution is to use `iptables` for that:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DNAT --to foo_serverip:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DNAT --to foo_serverip:443
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

will redirect all traffic in the interface `eth0` (option: -i) received on port 80 and 443 (option: --dport 80, 443) to a `foo_serverip` IP address on port 80 or 443.

After tested you can just save your current iptables rules with

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
```

and restore them with

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

Knowing this, the options to restore the rules at boot time are multiple. The most simple one I can think of is to edit your `/etc/rc.local` and append the line `/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules` to it.

I do not think `ufw` can do any of this just by itself.

Comment: if I enter this as sudo, should it work? I guess it would be lost at restart, do you know where I should put this regarding ufw?

Comment: @Olivier edited, let me know if you have any further doubts.

Comment: This worked, but I had to disable ufw.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to configure **ufw** to make port forward to external IP

1. edit `/etc/default/ufw` to accept forwarding requests

   `default_forward_policy = "accept"`
2. edit /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf to allow forwarding

   `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
3. edit `/etc/ufw/before.rules`, add the following after the first comment

   ```
   *nat
   :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
   -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination external_ip:80
   COMMIT
   ```

Comment: Hmm...what do you mean by `ff`?  I am not seeing that in the `/etc/ufw/before.rules` file.

Comment: It looks like my answer was changed. I don't know what is `ff` here

Comment: Seems this no longer works in 2023. Adding `default_forward_policy = "accept"` to `/etc/default/ufw` crashes my ufw service on restart.

Comment: @aggregate1166877 it works for me (DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"), anyway you can list status by "systemctl status ufw.service". I had an issue with additional line after last COMMIT at before.rules file.