# UFW forward port to internal IP

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ufw

I am running Ubuntu server 16.04. I want traffic coming in at port 80 and port 443 to go to one of my LXC containers I am running (let's say its IP is 10.20.0.100).

Is it possible with UFW to have the traffic going to these port redirected to my containers IP?

Comment: Yes, this is just creating a tunnel essentially - It can be done by creating a NAT Rule (vague answer at least - you'll need to research that a bit more - unfortunately I do not have enough time to go into detail)

Comment: I have tried to look it up, but it does not seem to work for now. I will try to get it working with this method. But if you can help me with an example, that would be great.

Comment: I'd take a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/411538/configure-ufw-to-redirect-http-traffic-to-another-ip -> It's exactly what i'm refering to. (You would just replace the destination server IP with that of the internal one you refer to) :)